# Unable to pass job parameters using Dataflow REST API

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to invoke a dataflow template via the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/create), however, when the **parameters** are specified in the body, an INVALID_ARGUMENT error is thrown. Upon removing the parameters field, it works fine though. I have tried both Javascript & Python but get exactly the same error.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

def invoke_dataflow_job():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)

    TEMPLATE_LOCATION = 'gs://xxx';
    PROJECT_ID = 'xxx';
    JOB_NAME = 'xxx';
    LOCATION = 'europe-west1';
    ZONE = 'europe-west1-b';
    TEMP_LOCATION = 'xxx';

    BODY = {
        'jobName': JOB_NAME,
        'gcsPath': TEMPLATE_LOCATION,
        'parameters': {
           'messageToPrint': 'Blue sky'
        },
        'environment': {
           'tempLocation': TEMP_LOCATION,
           'zone': ZONE,
        }
    }

    request = service.projects().locations().templates().create(projectId=PROJECT_ID, location=LOCATION, body=BODY)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
```

Does the REST API support passing in parameters? Looking at the [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates#using-the-google-api-client-libraries) code, I believe it should.

Any suggestions?

Error message:

```
The workflow could not be created. Causes: (4adc3dbfd180d8a2): Found unexpected parameters: ['messageToPrint' (perhaps you meant 'userAgent')]
```

**Update 1:**

Sample DoFn:

```
public static class BuildPathFn extends DoFn<String, Void> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2815123956194177539L;
    private final ValueProvider<String> baseDir; 
    private final ValueProvider<String> year; 
    private final ValueProvider<String> month; 
    private final ValueProvider<String> day; 
    private final ValueProvider<String> hour; 
    private final ValueProvider<String> filePattern; 

    public BuildPathFn (ValueProvider<String> baseDir, ValueProvider<String> year, 
                            ValueProvider<String> month, ValueProvider<String> day, 
                            ValueProvider<String> hour, ValueProvider<String> filePattern) {
        this.baseDir = baseDir;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.filePattern = filePattern;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element String element, OutputReceiver<Void> receiver) {
        try {
            String path = baseDir.get() + "/" + year.get() + "/" + month.get() + "/" + day.get() + "/" + hour.get() + "/" + filePattern.get();
            LOG.info("BuildPathFn >> Path: {}", path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("BuildPathFn >> Exception: {}", e.getMessage()); 

        }
    }
}
```

Runtime output:

```
BuildPathFn >> Path: true/true/true/true/true/true
```

Part of mvn command used to build the template:

```
 ".... --baseDir --year --month --day --hour --filePattern"
```

Comment: Just tested this and it works for me as long as the parameter is defined in the template. Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to test it. The parameter was definitely in the template, however, when compiling the template, I didn't include it as the parameter on the command line in the mvn compile. Having recompiled it with the added parameter, works like a charm. Many thanks. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. However, before doing that, I'd like to confirm if you are able to use a different parameter when invoking the template. Because I think if you specify it in the mvn command it might always resolve the original parameter as it happened for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561402/6121516)

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. I did look at the other question that you referred to, however, I am unable to read the value of the passed in values of the parameters. No error is thrown when the template is run. Please see Update 1 above.

Comment: Fixed it. I guess I wasn't reading your instructions in the other thread properly. At template generation time, need to totally remove the params from the mvn command. You can add it as the answer now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine and it's the correct way to pass parameters. Keep in mind that the option needs to be defined in the template as a [ValueProvider](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#modifying-your-code-to-use-runtime-parameters). When [staging](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates) the template don't pass any parameter that you want to be resolved at runtime. Then the option values should be evaluated when [invoking](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates) the template with the code already in the description (i.e. using `parameters` inside request body).