# Dataflow template job is not taking input parameters

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow template created with below command

```
    python scrap.py --setup_file /home/deepak_verma/setup.py
  --temp_location gs://visualization-dev/temp
 --staging_location gs://visualization-dev/stage 
--project visualization-dev --job_name scrap-job 
--subnetwork regions/us-east1/subnetworks/dataflow-internal 
--region us-east1  --input sentiment_analysis.table_view 
--output gs://visualization-dev/incoming 
--runner DataflowRunner 
--template_location gs://visualization-dev/template/scrap
```

My dataflow pipeline accepts the input and output parameters as value provider like this

```
@classmethod
def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--input', dest='input', required=True,
        help='Input view. sentiment_analysis.table_view',
    )

    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--output', dest='output', required=True,
        help='output gcs file path'
    )
```

and I am using this as

```
beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=read_query.format(
        table=options.input.get(), limit=(LIMIT and "limit " + str(LIMIT) or '')), use_standard_sql=True)))

where read_query is defined as `SELECT upc, max_review_date FROM `{table}`
```

Now when I call this template using this with different input parameter

```
template_body = {
                'jobName': job_name,
                'parameters': {'input': 'table_view2'}
            }
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
            service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
            request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(projectId=constants.GCP_PROJECT_ID, location=constants.REGION, gcsPath=template_gcs_path, body=template_body)
```

The dataflow does not calls this for table_view2 but instead it use the table_view for this job.

Comment: "instead it use the table_view for this job". I don't see where in your shared code blocks where `table_view` is written. Is there some information missing about the template?

Comment: please see the first command. It was not visible due to horizontal scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are already passing an `input` value when staging the template and that's the one being resolved. Remove `--input sentiment_analysis.table_view` when running the first command and leave it empty. Specify it only as a parameter when executing the template with `'parameters': {'input': 'sentiment_analysis.table_view2'}`.

If you still need a default value you can do it when adding the value provider argument like in [this example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/value_provider_test.py#L44):

```
parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--input', dest='input', required=True,
        help='Input view. sentiment_analysis.table_view',
        default='sentiment_analysis.table_view'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to be able to pass the query as a ValueProvider, and not as an already-formatted string. This is not yet possible in Beam.

There's an open feature request here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1440